# Your thoughts on a proposal to manage JavaScript dependencies

Tags: javascript, maven-2, dependencies, mojo

I've recently done a great deal of JavaScript programming in the context of developing a [Rich Internet Application](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rich_Internet_application). My view at the start of development is pretty much what it is now; JS RIA works but the development tools are lacking.

One tool that I missed in particular was for managing dependencies. What I found was that I ended up with lots of HTML pages declaring all of their JS file dependencies and that this became hard to maintain.

What I'd like to know are your thoughts on a project I've embarked upon: *Maven JavaScript Import*. My intent is to ultimately release the project as open source but at the moment I'm just tinkering around with it (a great deal has been developed already though).

**Declaring dependencies**

My thoughts based on using Maven to declare JS files as dependencies. This is how I'd declare a project dependency on jQuery in my pom file:

```
<dependency>
  <groupId>com.jquery</groupId>
  <artifactId>jquery</artifactId>
  <version>1.4.2</version>
  <type>js</type>
</dependency>
```

A file that then depends on jQuery has two methods of declaring its dependence:

1. via an @import statement within a comment block; or
2. simply declaring a global variable that's required.

**Imports**

Explicit imports take the form:

```
/**
 * @import com.jquery:jquery
 */
```

As you can see the format of the import is `<groupId>:<artifactId>`. The approach holds the advantage that there is no file/version information declared in the js file that has the dependency. These GAV parameters resolve to artifacts declared in the POM file.

**Global Vars**

Instead of the above @import, if a dependent file declares variables at the global scope then simply declaring any of those global symbols is all that is required. For example if a file requires jQuery:

```
var $;
```

... as $ is of course a global defined by jQuery.

Not all dependencies declare global symbols and that's why @import is proposed as well, but declaring the symbol required is, I think, nice and clean (and JSLint conforming!).

**In conclusion**

Ultimately the HTML file that requires a JS resource simply declares the immediate one it requires, and not all of its dependencies. My Maven plugin will run through all the JS files (source files and dependencies) and build a symbol tree. Any HTML file including a resource will have script elements injected by the plugin to ensure that all dependencies are included. This will all happen in the magical Maven way when a project's phases are executed e.g. prior to a test, or resources phase executes.

So what do you think? Is this something that you might use in your JS RIA project?

Comment: The Google Closure tools have a nice approach to managing dependencies. Every JS file declares its dependencies, and the compiler can then copy together everything that your "main" script file needs. They made GMail with these toolkits, so apparently it works.

Comment: Very interesting. Thanks for that; I shall look into the Closure Tools a bit more. One thing that I forgot to mention about my proposal is that the dependencies are brought in statically i.e. when the html document loads. I have not thoroughly explored Closure yet, but I'm getting the impression that the dependencies are brought in lazily as required. I have developed something along this path already and I know that debugging via FireBug and other methods didn't cope with this particularly well. Just a thought. Thanks again though - I'll take a closer look at Closure's mechanisms.

Comment: On further investigation I don't see that Closure manages versioning of dependencies - nor does there appear to be any concept of repositories... Maven is very strong in this regard of course.

Comment: "I have not thoroughly explored Closure yet, but I'm getting the impression that the dependencies are brought in lazily as required." No, only during development. For production use, everything gets compiled into a single file. But you are right, Closure does not manage versioning or repositories.

Comment: So its been more than a year.  Show me the code!

Comment: Just noticed your comment. The code has been available for some time. Please start here: http://mojo.codehaus.org/javascript-maven-tools/

Answer (score 1):

I agree that JavaScript developers are missing proper dependency management for their projects. I'm not following entirely how a HTML file would import just a single file js dependency and then end up with all the dependencies as well. Are you planning on filtering the HTML files and replacing the script import with an import of your concatenated classes?

If you're interested I've traveled the same road and ended up with https://github.com/ProggerPete/JavaScript-Tools. It's working fairly well for me.

Comment: The project is now live at the Codehaus: http://mojo.codehaus.org/js-import-maven-plugin/ In summary I do indeed filter the html files and inject a script's dependencies.

Answer (score 0):

I think that [Bower](https://github.com/bower/bower) is the fun & proper way to manage .js dependencies.